# How do I prevent two different behaviors at a single URL in Micro frontends

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, vite, webpack-module-federation

The Micro frontends are Client side rendered react applications bundled using vite

The host application loads Micro frontends corresponding to every item in the side navigation

The micro frontends are loaded at runtime in the host app using vite's Module federation

This is the folder structure of built assets

[image: Folder structure of built assets]

I am intentionally adding the `assets` in folders like `foo/assets`, `bar/assets` respectively for every Micro frontend so that the `remoteEntry.js` file is available via the Load Balancer

The client side rendered react applications are built and the static contents are stored in respective Google Cloud storage buckets

The Cloud storage buckets are set as the backends of Load balancer in URL Map at different paths described as below

`* -> Host application`

`/dashboard -> Dashboard micro-frontend`

`/foo -> Foo micro-frontend`

`/bar -> Bar micro-frontend`

When the user types `app.myDomain.com`, The browser loads the container which has navigation

Then when the user clicks on a navigation item, Lets say `dashboard`, Then we load the Dashboard micro frontend, Whose remote entry URL is configured as

`https://app.myDomain.com/dashboard/assets/dashboard.js`,

I have intentionally modified the `assetsDir` of vite to send assets to `foo/assets` as that the `remoteEntry.js` file is available as `foo/assets/foo.js` in respective Cloud storage buckets

Now coming to the problem -

1. The user entered the URL `app.myDomain.com` and was served the correct Host application
2. The user clicked on `dashboard` link in navigation and the correct Micro frontend was Lazy loaded at runtime from its respective Cloud storage bucket and the remoteEntry path was `http://app.myDomain.com/dashboard/assets/dashboard.js`. (When the request passed through Google Cloud's load balancer, It sent it to the correct Dashboard micro frontend bucket based on `/dashboard/*` in path and the exposed federated Module was loaded )
3. Now the user either hits refresh or shares the URL , Now the GET request that originates is sent directly to Dashboard micro frontend's bucket and the Dashboard application loads independently in the browser instead of the exposed federated Dashboard module inside the host application, This was because the load balancer saw `/dashboard` in URL and directly sent request to Dashboard bucket instead of Host application's bucket?

So now what has happened is, If the user comes on `app.myDomain.com/dashboard` by navigating from the host application then correct Dashboard component loads inside Host application and if the user directly hits `app.myDomain.com/dashboard` in the browser searchbox then the dashboard application loads independently

Expected behavior - The exposed micro frontend must load inside host application instead of remote application loading independently

Any solution to solve this problem?

Things I tried - Using HashRouter

Then the URLS became

`app.myDomain.com/#/dashboard` -> this request will always load the dashboard inside host application

`app.myDomain.com/dashboard/#/foo` -> this request will load the remote micro frontend independently

But I am not keen to use the above solution and would want alternatives